# How to get category name dynamicaly on product page magento2?

Tags: magento2, category

> I want to show category name dynamicly on product page help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product can have multiple categories, like a product is selected in actual category, which could be 2nd or 3rd level, but the same product could also be selected in **Sale** category, or any other category.

So, in order to get actual category you can do this:

```
    $categoryCollection = clone $product->getCategoryCollection();
    $categoryCollection->clear();
    $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSort('level', $categoryCollection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/" . $storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() . "/%"));
    $categoryCollection->setPageSize(1);
    $treeCategories = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem()->getParentCategories();
    $tree = [];
    foreach ($treeCategories as $category) {
        $tree[] = $category->getName();
    }
```

where `$storeManager` is the instance of `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface`, which usually send id 2, which is root category of your store.

Now in `$tree`, you will get the tree of your product category, like `Grocery -> Food -> Rice`

Comment: how to move category in middle after product using layout ?

Comment: If you have idea please help me

Comment: Are you talking about CSS?

Comment: No i am talking about layout , there is any way to move category page in middle using layout ?

Comment: Sorry bro, no idea

Comment: @Shoib Munir Ok bro no problem

Answer (score 1):

I am expecting you have product object.

If you do not have product then first get object of product using below code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
```

$categories will return array of category ids.

```
foreach($categories as $category){
    $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
    echo $cat->getName();
}
```

If this helps you then hit like and accept as answer.

Thank you

Hiren Patel

Adobe Certified Professional—Adobe Commerce Developer

Comment: thanks ,  but I am getting category name above product name ,I want to call it product footer help me please

Comment: Yes you can call custom block in catalog_product_view.xml.

that block will be in footer area.

for example :

<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
<block name="product-categories" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" templates="Magento_Catalog::product/view/categories.phtml" before="-" />
</referenceContainer>

Comment: this is not working for me

Comment: I am using <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Module" name="product-categories" template="Vendor_Module::currentCategory.phtml" before="-" />
        </referenceContainer>

Comment: That will also fine. I can show you place :) but this is your choice if you would like to go with new module or theme :)

Comment: but this is not working fine

Comment: I want to move category in middle after product help me please